# gmail - programatically auto forward users email (oauth login)

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap, email-forwarding

I want to create a filter for auto forwarding specific incoming mails to my users Gmail account.

I have a OAuth login key to my  users account. I can use it to search and forward the existing mails, but can I change the auto forwarding settings programmatically?

Comment: Only for Google Apps accounts.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_forwarding_settings

Comment: @SLaks - thanks. I guess you can't do any management for a general (non google apps) account

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically change users' auto-forwarding settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).